# Mount home partition after login

Tags: linux, partition, security, users, luks

I am looking for a way to set up a Linux box where I would have a user's home folder reside on a separate encrypted password-protected partition (perhaps using LUKS? Not sure what the current best practice is), and I would like their home folder to be mounted only when they log in.

So the user enters their password, then gets prompted for the home partition password, and only then the login succeeds.

My hunch as to how to do it is probably via the `.bashrc` file, but the login shell looks for that file in the home folder -- which obviously wouldn't be accessible until the folder is mounted and decrypted (chicken & egg problem).

I suppose one solution could be to have a locally-mounted dummy home folder for that user on the main drive, with just the `.bashrc` file which would run all of the partition initialization logic and then mount the encrypted partition over itself. However, this feels a bit hacky and I'm not sure if it would even work. In addition, it would be impossible to edit that `.bashrc` file from the user's session (unless I were to add more hacks to have the transient `.bashrc` file execute the "real" one after the part is mounted).

So I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?

(**Note:** I did see this question -- [Mount home partition on user login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106554/mount-home-partition-on-user-login) -- but do not consider mine to be a duplicate, because: (1) that question is 10 years old and things may have changed by now, and (2) I am not looking for workarounds (and definitely nothing using FUSE); I would like this to be as seamless as possible without any additional overhead; the current process is to log in as root, mount the user's home partition, and then log in as the user; I would simply like to streamline this for the sole sake of user convenience/experience and would thus like to avoid any sort of tradeoffs -- especially when it comes to performance).

Comment: What you want is called "encrypted home directories". Your Operating System may already have the feature. It's harder than you think - the decrypted directory must be available at `login` time. Ubuntu did it with a decrypting filesystem and an overlay mount.

Comment: The referenced solution (`ecryptfs`) and PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules), while 10 years old, should point you in the right direction. That direction is `ecryptfs` and `PAM`. As for your desire to "avoid overhead" is laudable, it's a fantasy. "Avoid unnecessary Overhead", maybe. Unless you measure (or trust some other measurement) overhead, don't complain.

Comment: I used "encrypted home directory" (`ecryptfs`) for years. I never had problems, and didn't notice the overhead. I stopped, so that my backups(encrypted) would give me something readable (unencrypted) on other systems. This is not your case. YMMV.

Comment: Life is "tradeoffs". In 1967, when I was `EE09WS12` (later `CC01WS12` at CMU, inctruction times were in milliseconds. "Overhead" mattered. If you are afflicted with slowness, blaming "overhead" is lazy. You cannot "do a new thing" without "tradeoffs".